# Spring Boot PostMapping: How to enforce JSON decoding if no Content-Type present

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm implementing a simple rest controller with Spring Boot (2.3.2) to receive data from an external source via POST. That source doesn't send a Content-Type with it, but provides a body containing JSON.

My controller is really simple

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WaitTimeImportController {
    private final StorageService storageService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/endpoint")
    public void setWaitTimes(@RequestBody DataObject toStore) {
        storageService.store(toStore);
    }
}
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class DataObject {
  private String data;
}
@Service
class StorageService {
    void store(DataObject do) {
        System.out.println("received");
    }
}
```

Now, if I send it a json String, it will not trigger that request mapping.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class WaittimesApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void happyPath() throws IOException {
        WebClient client = client();

        String content = "{ \"data\": \"test\"} ";
        AtomicBoolean ab = new AtomicBoolean();
        await().atMost(Duration.FIVE_SECONDS).ignoreExceptions()
            .until(() -> {
                ClientResponse response = client.post()
                        // .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .bodyValue(content)
                        .exchange()
                        .timeout(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(200))
                        .block();
        ab.set(response.statusCode() == HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
                return ab.get();
            });
    }
}
```

This test fails unless I uncomment the "header" line above; then it is fine.

Since I have no influence over the source submitting the POST request, I cannot add `application/json` as the request header.

I've been searching a lot about content negotiation in Spring, but nothing I've tried worked.

- adding a `consumes="application/json"` to the `@PostMapping` annotation
- adding a `consumes=MediaType.ALL_VALUE` to the `@PostMapping` annotation
- adding a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean didn't work
- adding a `ContentNegotiationStrategy` bean didn't compile "cannot access javax.servlet.ServletException" - is it a worthwhile route to pursue this?

What can I do to enforce the mapping to accept a non-"Content-Type" request and decode it as JSON?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the `consume` attribute of the `PostMapping` annotation. It seems to work in a more specific way.

Comment: @Lebecca Yes, I tried that (added it to the list in the question, thanks for reminding me). IIUC, that is only used by Spring to map incoming requests that do contain a Content-Type header entry.

Comment: I mean, since you are marking what type of HTTP request can be accepted, how about set the consumes to `consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE`, not `application/json`

Comment: @Lebecca I'm not sure I tried that before (I think I did), but it doesn't work either. Also added to the list.

Comment: Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133429/spring-mvc-requestbody-when-no-content-type-is-specified) solving the problem using the filter to set `content-type` for request. Not that elegant but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uggg. So Lebecca's comment sent on a wild run through how to adjust header field with Spring (I'm using webflux, so the linked solution was not applicable as such), and I couldn't find a proper tutorial on it and the documentation is a bit distributed amongst several pages you come across when searching.

There are a few roadblocks, so here's a condensed version.

**Clean way: Adjusting the header to inject the Content-Type`**

So what you can do is create a `WebFilter` that gets evaluated before the request actually reaches the mapping. Just define a `@Component` that implements it.

To add to the `ServerWebExchange` object that gets passed, you wrap it in a `ServerWebExchangeDecorator`.

```
@Component
class MyWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(new MyServerExchangeDecorator(exchange));
    }
}
```

That decorator can manipulate both the request and the response; just override the appropriate method. Of course, the request needs to be decorated as well - can't go around working on the original object (it actually throws an exception if you try to set its properties because it's read only).

```
class MyServerExchangeDecorator extends ServerWebExchangeDecorator {

    protected MyServerExchangeDecorator(ServerWebExchange delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }
    @Override
    public ServerHttpRequest getRequest() {
        return new ContentRequestDecorator(super.getRequest());
    }
}
```

Now you just implement the `ContentRequestDecorator` and you're good to go.

```
class ContentRequestDecorator extends ServerHttpRequestDecorator {

    public ContentRequestDecorator(ServerHttpRequest delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }
    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(super.getHeaders());
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        return httpHeaders;
    }
}
```

Trying to just call `setContentType` on the object being passed in results in an `OperationNotSupportedException` because, again, it is read only; hence the `HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders()` call.

Of course, this will adjust all headers for all incoming requests, so if you plan on doing this and don't want the nuclear option, inspect the request beforehand.

**The simple way**

So the way above triggers Springs mapping of the incoming request to a `consumes="application/json"` endpoint.

However, if you didn't read my previous description as containing a slightly sarcastic undertone, I should have been less subtle. It's a very involved solution for a very simple problem.

The way I actually ended up doing it was

```
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @PostMapping(value = "/endpoint")
    public void setMyData(HttpEntity<String> json) {
        try {
            MyData data = mapper.readValue(json.getBody(), MyData.class);
            storageService.setData(data);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().build();
        }
    }
```