# Receive RESTFUL request without Content-Type header

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am practicing spring boot and meet a problem.
I have a restful API to receive requests from other 3rd parties. May I know is it possible to receive the request without a Content-Type header.
I keep facing error 415-Unsupported Media Type due to request without Content-Type=application/JSON. The problem solves if the request comes with the ContentType header.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "backend", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> Backend(@RequestBody RequestDto RequestDto) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Service.process(RequestDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```

This is my code for the rest API. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Without content-type server is not able to parse the request input stream, in that case server refuse the input stream.

Comment: @daniu Yes this is exactly what i need. Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply and appreciate everyone who trying to help me.
I found the answer from the link sent by @daniu.
Source : [Solution to receive request without Content-Type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922374/spring-boot-postmapping-how-to-enforce-json-decoding-if-no-content-type-present)
The solution is instead of using @RequestBody provided by springboot, we manually mapping the json string into object by using Gson.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "backend", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> Backend(HttpEntity<String> json) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    ResponseDto ResponseDto = utils.gsonBuilder().fromJson(json.getBody(), ResponseDto.class);
    BackendService.process(ResponseDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```