# How to define a rest service without content-type in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, rest, content-type

I have a spring boot project and one of the clients asked us to provide a rest service without a content-type header, in other words, the client doesn't specify the content-type.

I have done like this :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/mock/iban/")
public class IbanController {

   @PostMapping(value="/payment")
   ResponseEntity<PaymentResponse> payment(@RequestBody Document doc){
      PaymentResponse response = new PaymentResponse();
      return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

I didn't specify any accept content type here, but when the client sends the request as below :

[image]

The client gets 400 bad request errors and the breakpoint in the method doesn't hit.

I searched in many tutorials and all of them talking about how to define a service with a specific content-type and none of them tell me how to define without contnet-type.

Comment: Have you already looked at the following SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922374/spring-boot-postmapping-how-to-enforce-json-decoding-if-no-content-type-present?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `produces` attribute to `@RequestMapping` as follows:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/mock/iban/", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class IbanController {

   @PostMapping(value="/payment")
   ResponseEntity<PaymentResponse> payment(@RequestBody Document doc){
      PaymentResponse response = new PaymentResponse();
      return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

But to be honest I am not sure if you will be able to do this. Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't the client send such a standard HTTP header?

Comment: Thanks, But it doesn't work like that, we don't have any issue for response content-type, the issue is incoming requests without content-type. for your curiosity, I don't know. the central bank has given us this instruction, I have some thought though, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Check @Gregor Zurowski comment. It might help!